# my headset mic produces like an engine noises

Tags: laptop, audio-recording, headset

It was alright until yesterday, today I have been hearing very irritating noise from my headset. This noise increases when I touch to microphone tip(part very close to mouth, voice receiver). But while touching to HDMI port with my other hand then the noise disappears.what must be happened and what can be caused that issue?

[sample record with noise](http://ahmetbergmann.com/files/audio/noises.wav)

Comment: Is the cable/port damaged somehow?

Comment: There is no problem with sounds, noise arises only when I set microphone plug. I can listen to music.

Comment: You've got a damaged cable or socket. That sounds like a floating earth [signal ground]. Touching something else with a good ground fixes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your headset is damaged and connecting to the ground wire, the electricity flowing to ground could be generating this "engine sound" on your headset, especially if there is one connected to the same power supply (fans, hard drives and optical drives, all have motors inside. Try your headset in another computer and try a new headset on your computer to check if what I am sayin is true.

In case this isn't the case, try plugging your computer on a grounded outlet, this could solve your problem in case the headset is fine.

Comment: I moved laptop to the kitchen, noise has gone, I don't' know what is there in my brother's room. Now everything is OK. Actually I was strugling with this issue for hours it took my time, I did not eat anything. I didn't go fitness. Thank you for your advices this fixed my issue.